# Getting reference to an item using AngularFire2

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2, angularfire5

I am using AF2 v5 and using the Real-time database.

I want to get the reference to a node or item in my data. After checking the docs I found the following.

```
const listRef = db.list('items');
```

Notice the user of the `.list()` method. The return type of the above statement is `AngularFireList{[]}`.

I was hoping to get the return type of `Reference`.

Is this the correct way to get a reference to a node so that I can perform CRUD to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `db.object()` to get a single `firebase.database.Reference`.

```
const item = db.object('items/itemID').valueChanges();
```

Check the official [doc](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/objects.md#create-an-object-binding)

You can perform the CRUD like

```
const itemRef = db.object('items/itemID');

itemRef.remove();

itemRef.set({ name: 'new name!'});

itemRef.update({ age: newAge });
```

Comment: I don't know why you would call this a `DocumentReference`. The return value from `db.object` is `AngularFireObject`, right? I think the OP (although he does say he wants to do CRUD on it), or at least I, wants to get the `firebase.database.Reference` corresponding to the `AngularFireObject` or `AngularFireList`.

Comment: @torazaburo you are right. i mixed my head with `firestore` database. It should be `firebase.database.Reference`. And `AngularFireObject` is just a wrapper around `firebase.database.Reference` [link](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/src/database/interfaces.ts).